# Wordpress woocommerce - hide flat rate when free shipping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I have one wordpress/woocommerce site. When user cart amount is over 500 i must have free shipping in cart subtotal. Right now i have setup flat rate 25 and free shipping if amount is more then 500.

I google it from help and add some code into functions.php but still have same problem.

```
    function hide_all_shipping_when_free_is_available( $available_methods ) {

if( isset( $available_methods['free_shipping'] ) ) :

// Get Free Shipping array into a new array
$freeshipping = array();
$freeshipping = $available_methods['free_shipping'];

// Empty the $available_methods array
unset( $available_methods );

// Add Free Shipping back into $avaialble_methods
$available_methods = array();
$available_methods['free_shipping'] = $freeshipping;

endif;

return $available_methods;
}
```

i use wordpress with woocommerce 2.3.8 on Oxygen theme.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the old method, you need to use this [new one](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/) I think.

Copied from WooThemes website:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates','hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 10, 2 );

function hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates, $package ) {

    // Only modify rates if free_shipping is present
    if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping'] ) ) {

        // To unset a single rate/method, do the following. This example unsets flat_rate shipping
        unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );

        // To unset all methods except for free_shipping, do the following
        $free_shipping          = $rates['free_shipping'];
        $rates                  = array();
        $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but stil no working. I have the same situation. i just add your code to functions.php but still have 2 shipping cost (paid and free)

Comment: I don't have a woocommerce installation now, but are you sure that the shipping method has the names or ID's in the backend like in the code? in this case "flat_rate" and "free_shipping?" @custombrands

Comment: Yes, i just verify and in check out page i have value="flat_rate" wich is checked and value="free_shipping"

Comment: I just update woocommerce to latest 2.3.9 version. Right now is ok! Thanks and best regards.